# Web3. Websocket connection closed. An error occurred: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Tags: web3.py, python, websocket, async

I'm trying to receive pending transactions from the `eth mempool`, for which I use a `wss` connection to the node.

The problem is that when normally receiving messages from the node, no errors occur and the cycle is not interrupted.

however, if I add transaction verification via web3, after a couple of minutes of the software running, an error occurs.

I tried using both **websocket** and **websockets** libs but the problem remains.

In **websocket**:

```
ERROR:root:An error occurred: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

and in **websockets**:

```
Future exception was never retrieved
future: <Future finished exception=ConnectionClosedError(None, None, None)>
websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedError: no close frame received or sent
```

**websocket** code:

```
def on_message(ws, message):
    timing = time.perf_counter()
    try:
        if 'eth_subscription' in message:
            tx = json.loads(message)
            try:
                tx = web3.eth.get_transaction(tx['params']['result'])
                print(tx)
            except TransactionNotFound:
                pass
            #Thread(target=get_tx, args=(tx_hash,)).start()
    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
    finally:
        print(colored(str(time.perf_counter() - timing), 'magenta'))


def on_error(ws, error):
    print(error)

def on_close(ws, close_status_code, close_msg):
    print("### closed ###")

def on_open(ws):
    print("Opened connection")



def main():
    try:
        websocket.enableTrace(True, level='INFO')
        ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://localhost:7546", on_open=on_open, on_message=on_message, on_error=on_error,
                                    on_close=on_close,)

        subscribe_request = {
                        "id": 1,
                        "method": "eth_subscribe",
                        "params": [
                            "newPendingTransactions"
                        ],
                        "jsonrpc": "2.0"
                    }
        ws.run_forever(dispatcher=rel, reconnect=5, sslopt={"cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_NONE})
        ws.send(json.dumps(subscribe_request))
        rel.signal(2, rel.abort)
        rel.dispatch()
    except Exception as err:
        logging.error(f"An error occurred: {err}")



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**websockets** code:

```
async def get_event():
    async with websockets.connect(node_ws_url, ping_timeout=None) as ws:

            await ws.send('{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 1, "method": "eth_subscribe", "params": ["newPendingTransactions"]}')
            subscription_response = await ws.recv()
            print(subscription_response)

            while True:
                try:
                    message = await asyncio.wait_for(ws.recv(), timeout=60)
                    #print("Received message:", message)
                    response = json.loads(message)
                    txHash = response['params']['result']
                    tx = web3.eth.get_transaction(txHash)
                    print(tx)
                except TransactionNotFound:
                    pass
                except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed as e:
                    logging.error(f"Connection closed: {e}")
                    break
                except Exception as e:
                    logging.error(f"An error occurred: {e}")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    while True:
        loop.run_until_complete(get_event())
```

Answer (score 0):

your node might be closing the connection, or (in this case) it is interrupted for some reason. yes, I know, pretty obvious. it happens, connections break. you need to setup connection recovery, eg. just call `get_events` back when the exception is caught?

also I recommend using a node with a more stable connection to begin with. a few minutes is too quick to consistently dropping connections.

Comment: Hello. I'm afraid that the problem is definitely not with the socket. I tried to implement the same functionality using ethers and tokio. there the loop runs endlessly and without stops or failures. so the problem lies in the implementation in Python.

Regarding get_events, I honestly don’t understand what we’re talking about